# Set Theory Problem bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is a countably infinite set and $B$ is a finite set with
    $A \cap N = \emptyset,$ then $A \cup B$ is a countably infinite set.
    Obviously, this is a biject-with-the-naturals problem, but I am
    having difficulties seeing how to biject this exactly.

By their
    set-theoretic properties, $|B| = b < \infty \implies$ there exists
    a bijection $f: B \rightarrow [b]$ and there exists a bijection 
    $g: A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}.$ however, I feel if I were to make
    a function with the two of them, I would need to push some elements
    in $A$ ``farther up the naturals'' from where they were originally
    bijected to, correct?

Maybe my intuition is not quite with this
    problem.

Comment: That's right. Now it is a matter of writing it up.  For fun you might want to look up Hilbert's infinite hotel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply make a bijection from $A\cup B$ to $\Bbb N$ as first map all elements of $B$ to ${1,2,...,b}$ and then translate your bijection from $A$ to $\Bbb N$ by $b$.

By translation I mean, $f(x)= x+b.$

Clearly this will be a bijection.